# How to remove custom forms from library

Tags: 2013, list, document-library, custom-form, list-form

I migrated a doc library which had a custom form. On uploading a new document at the destination the new item form is blank. Can i remove this custom form and set to OOTB form?

Answer (score 1):

Use this script to set default edit form and display form URLs.

```
$w = Get-SPWeb "http://sp2013/sites/test"
$l = $w.Lists["Documents"]

$l.DefaultEditFormUrl = "$($l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)/Forms/EditForm.aspx"
$l.DefaultDisplayFormUrl = "$($l.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)/Forms/DispForm.aspx"

$l.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go into the `Library Settings > Form Settings` and select `Use the default SharePoint form`